# Change all Google Sheet worksheet names based on cell in each worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this script that will change a specified worksheet name based on a cell in that worksheet (from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/--zpRodmoX8/f3J248K9i-YJ)):

```
function renameSheet() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[2];
  s.setName(s.getRange(1, 2).getValue());

}
```

How would I modify this script to change all worksheet names (I'll use a trigger for every hour) based on the B1 cell in each worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ID with the spreadheet's ID since it will not be active when accessed from the time trigger

```
function renameSheet() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets();
  for(i in s) {
  s[i].setName(s[i].getRange(1, 2).getValue());
  }
}
```

A spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is "abc1234567".

Comment: And thanks for the update regarding using the ID rather than the active sheet - makes sense!